E: Unable to locate package openjdk-14-jre E: Unable to locate package openjdk-14-jdk
bash ./PX4-Autopilot/Tools/setup/ubuntu.sh
I am trying to install PX4 but I get this error. I also try to install openjdk-14-jdk. I get same error again.
sudo apt install openjdk-14-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-14-jdk
Installing PX4 simulation dependencies
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
bc is already the newest version (1.07.1-3ubuntu4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-14-jre
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-14-jdk

That seems to be an issue with the script, since openjdk-14-jre is not found in any current release

Should I change openjdk 21 istead of openjdk14

TBH I don't know - it's not clear to me why the author decided to try to install a specific JRE version (instead of installing the default-jre dependency package). The script only claims to work for "Ubuntu LTS (22.04, 20.04, 18.04)" - if you're using anything else then you may need to improvise.

I am using 24.04. You are right (I wrote 17 instead of 14 and the problem was solved)
